# Error in doFinal on multiple DES_CBC_NOPAD encryption

Tags: encryption, javacard, des

I had a problem with DES encryption on Java Card: I encrypt the data before sending it and then send it as a response to requests coming from some library.

If in one  applet `SELECT` sends requests for information, then through 28-30 encryptions on the card the session falls with the error `6F00`. After that, all encryption calls return `6F00`. The problem disappears if you do a second selection of the applet.

All data before encryption, I make a multiple of 8, so the error due to the length of the message I eliminated immediately. There may be a memory problem, but I call `JCSystem.requestObjectDeletion();` after each sending of data.

Below is the initialization and encryption function implemented in my Applet.

```
public static void Init()
    rw_des_key = (DESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES3_3KEY, false);
    rw_cipherDes = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_NOPAD, false);
    rw_des_key.setKey(rwdeskey, (short) 0);
}

public static short RWEncrypt(byte[] msg, short pos, short len, byte[] encMsg, short encPos) throws ArithmeticException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, ArrayStoreException, ClassCastException, IndexOutOfBoundsException, NegativeArraySizeException, NullPointerException, RuntimeException, SecurityException {
        rw_cipherDes.init(rw_des_key, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
        return rw_cipherDes.doFinal(msg, (short) pos, len, encMsg, (short) encPos);}
```

If someone can tell what might be the case, then I will be very grateful!

Comment: Resource leakage is not completely avoided by calling `requestObjectDeletion`: if references are kept then those resources will not be freed. Note that object deletion may only be executed at startup and may take lots of time - you want to avoid that at all costs after issuing the card. By the way, you can use backticks to mark inline code, and you can introduce sections by creating white lines in the markdown editor (or double space, enter to just introduce a new line in the same section).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem occurs when external access (externalAccess) flag is false in the object but the corresponding object is called by a shareable interface.

For example (from your code): -

> rw_cipherDes = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_NOPAD, false);

Here the external access flag is False i.e. you are instructing the Cipher API **not** to provide the access of cipher object to any external application (which is for the case of calling this API by shareable interface).

So, the following line will generate a security exception (hence SW 6F00) when called from across applications by shareable interface.

> return rw_cipherDes.doFinal(msg, (short) pos, len, encMsg, (short)
>   encPos);}

Obviously,when you call the same API from its own application, then it will work fine.

Solution is allowing `externalAccess (true)` for the object. This would make it accessible via shareable interface.

> rw_cipherDes = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_NOPAD, true);

Answer (score 0):

I Fix my broblem by changing **externalAccess** flag from False to True in **Cipher.getInstance** function:

```
Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_NOPAD, true);
```

It's resolve my problem.

Comment: This is not an answer. Do you have any explanation why this helped? If I were you, I would delete this answer and wait for a real explanation...